# Amazon Mechanical Turk one assignment at time

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I wonder if it's possible to implement the following scenario with Amazon Mechanical Turk.

I want to create a HIT with 50 assignments, but with only one assignment in process at any time. So that I don't allow more than one assignment in progress.

Is it possible? I didn't find something similar in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanical Turk does not support a time release feature.

However you can implement this programmatically by creating a new HIT at regular intervals.

If your HIT is an external link you may use TurkPrime.com which has a microbatch feature which supports time delays between releasing new HITs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I do need to implement external question.

Answer (score 1):

You can "add assignments" to a HIT, either through the web interface (see "Manage HITs Individually" page) or via the API. That would require you to manually add an assignment after each is submitted. Alternatively, via the API, you could write some kind of app that would check for submitted status and add one assignment periodically.